# Why do I keep getting a "400 invalid to header" response when using the Google GMail playground?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I have spent two days trying to send an email via [Google OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) with no luck. Here is the raw message I am trying to send:

```
To: "Stanley Smith" <stan.smith@yahoo.com>\r\nContent-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nSubject: this would be the subject\r\n\r\nThis is the email sent by Stanley Smith
```

I base64 encode (url-safe encode) that and then put the encoded string in the request body as such

```
{
    "raw": "VG86ICJTdGFubGV5IFNtaXRoIiA8c3Rhbi5zbWl0aEB5YWhvby5jb20+XHJcbkNvbnRlbnQtdHlwZTogdGV4dC9odG1sO2NoYXJzZXQ9aXNvLTg4NTktMVxyXG5NSU1FLVZlcnNpb246IDEuMFxyXG5TdWJqZWN0OiB0aGlzIHdvdWxkIGJlIHRoZSBzdWJqZWN0XHJcblxyXG5UaGlzIGlzIHRoZSBlbWFpbCBzZW50IGJ5IFN0YW5sZXkgU21pdGgK"
}
```

I then click send request and I keep getting this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 188
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Expires: Fri, 16 Dec 2016 15:27:27 GMT
Vary: Origin,X-Origin
Server: GSE
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Fri, 16 Dec 2016 15:27:27 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400, 
    "message": "Invalid to header", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Invalid to header", 
        "reason": "invalidArgument"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am following RFC 2822 so I have no idea why I am getting this error. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Try to first build the message with headers likeFrom and Subject then encode the message before sending it. Then follow the [Sending Email guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#sending_messages).

Comment: Does [**this minimal example**](http://pastebin.com/sKCqra2n) work for you?

Comment: @noogui This isn't related to the actual API. I am simply trying to use the playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: @Tholle That worked! Thanks. If you submit that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you get this error. It works if you rearrange the headers and encode it to base64 url-safe:

```
btoa(
  "From: \"Stanley Toles\" <stan.toles@yahoo.com>\r\n" +
  "To: \"Stanley Toles\" <stan.toles@yahoo.com>\r\n" +
  "Subject: this would be the subject\r\n" +
  "Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n" +

  "This is the email sent by Stanley Toles"
).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

This post helped me a lot. Thanks for asking the question Rob.

Originally, I was using the following code for the email message:

```
let email = {message: "To: firstname lastname<someperson@gmail.com>  From: firstname 
lastname <someperson@gmail.com> Subject: Saying Hello  Date: Tue, 9 Nov 2018 17:20:06 
-0600 
Message-ID: <1234@local.machine.example>  This is a message just to say hello."}
```

After reading your post I realized I was missing the return characters. Here is my finalized answer that sends an email out using google gmail api in javascript:

```
function sendMessage(auth) {

    let email = {message: `To: "first last" <someperson@gmail.com>\r\nContent-type: 
    text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nSubject: this would be the 
    subject\r\n\r\nThis is the email sent by Stanley Toles`}

    let base64EncodedEmail = Base64.encodeURI(email.message);

    gmail.users.messages.send({'auth': auth, 'userId': 'me',  'resource': {
     "payload": {
      "headers": [
       {name: "To", value: "first last <somepersonsemail@gmail.com>"},
       {name: 'From', value: 'first last <somepersonsemail@gmail.com>'},
       {name: 'Subject', value: 'Saying Hello'}]
    },
    'raw': base64EncodedEmail,


    }},function(err,response){

    if(err) throw err;

    console.log(response);
   });
  }
```